# ui-bootstrap datepicker enable weekend days

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

at the moment my datepicker works fine. But I need to fix something.
Saturdays and Sundays days are **disabled**, so they can't be selected.

[image: datepicker]

As I know, the official documentaion says nothing about this feature. Maybe with *template-url*, but anyway dont know where to find it.

Any idea? I think it's really easy to solve it.

Since it's in spanish, I need to enable `sab.` and `dom.` columns.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you refer the [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker), disabled dates is achieved by:

**JS**:

```
// Disable weekend selection
 $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
  };
```

**HTML:**

So, you can enable weekends by removing this chunk of code from your datepicker's code, i.e removing the `date-disabled` attribute passed to datepicker:

`date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"`

**Complete HTML:**

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
```

Comment: I feel so dumb now. I was sure it wasn't in the html code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**You do not have to change any html.** You can just put in `dateOptions` in controller:

```
    $scope.dateOptions = {
        dateDisabled: false
    };
```

and remember to add `datepicker-options="dateOptions"` to your `input` in html (btw other specified in html options can be moved to controller, too):

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
```